# Operation parameter must be str while inserting values to table in sql3 python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am getting an error message stating
ValueError: operation parameter must be str
while inserting data into the table

here is my code below

```
import csv
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('results.db')
curs = conn.cursor()

total = []
headerlist = []
headerlisttype = []

rowindex = 1
def parse_csv():
    '''
    Adds all the rows in csv file to total list
    '''
    with open('3-1 RESULTS.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        parser = csv.reader(csvfile)
        headerlist = next(parser)
        for row in parser:
            total.append(row)
# end parse_csv



def create_table():
    '''
    Creates a table with just auto incremented SNO column
    '''
    sql = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS RESULTS31
    (SNO NUMBER NOT NULL, REGNUMBER NUMBER, NAME TEXT, 
    MPII TEXT, SP TEXT, CG TEXT, FLAT TEXT, FS TEXT, OS TEXT,
    OSLAB TEXT, MPIILAB TEXT, SS TEXT, SGPA REAL, CGPA REAL) '''
    curs.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
#end create_table function


def insert_to_table(row):
    global rowindex
    sno = rowindex
    rowindex += 1

    reg, name, mpII, sp, cg, flat, fs, os, oslab, mpIIlab, ss, sgpa, cgpa = row

    sql = '''INSERT INTO RESULTS31
    (SNO NUMBER NOT NULL, REGNUMBER NUMBER, NAME TEXT, 
    MPII TEXT, SP TEXT, CG TEXT, FLAT TEXT, FS TEXT, OS TEXT,
    OSLAB TEXT, MPIILAB TEXT, SS TEXT, SGPA REAL, CGPA REAL) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ''', 
    (int(sno), int(reg), name, mpII, sp, cg, flat, fs, os, oslab, mpIIlab, ss, float(sgpa), float(cgpa))

    try:
        curs.execute(sql)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def print_from_table():
    sql = ''' SELECT * FROM RESULTS31 '''
    curs.execute(sql)

    data = curs.fetchall()

    for row in data:
        print(row)

parse_csv()
create_table()

for row in total:
    insert_to_table(row)

print_from_table()
```

can anyone please find the error in my code
Help will be much apreciated

Comment: To prevent your code from sql injection attacks, use parameter substation. For more reference take a loot at https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Edit your question and show the **full error message**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INSERT wants only the column names, not any column types.
And `execute()` has two parameters, the SQL statement text, and the list of SQL parameters:

```
sql = '''INSERT INTO RESULTS31 (SNO, REGNUMBER, ...'''
params = (int(sno), ...)
curs.execute(sql, params)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this Python construct:

> ```
> sql = '''INSERT INTO RESULTS31
> (SNO NUMBER NOT NULL, REGNUMBER NUMBER, NAME TEXT, 
> MPII TEXT, SP TEXT, CG TEXT, FLAT TEXT, FS TEXT, OS TEXT,
> OSLAB TEXT, MPIILAB TEXT, SS TEXT, SGPA REAL, CGPA REAL) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ''', 
> (int(sno), int(reg), name, mpII, sp, cg, flat, fs, os, oslab, mpIIlab, ss, float(sgpa), float(cgpa))
> ```

Unless this is perfectly valid syntax for formatting strings, your code will create a tuple and bind it to 'sql'

look into [format()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)